# requirement failed: OneHotEncoderModel expected x categorical values for input column label, but the input column had metadata specifying n values

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

While training MultilayerPerceptronClassifier in Pyspark (version 2.4.5), I am getting the following exception:

`requirement failed: OneHotEncoderModel expected x categorical values for input column label, but the input column had metadata specifying n values.`

But the code is working fine with RandomForestClassifier, DecisionTreeClassifier, GBTClassifier, and  LinearSVC for the same dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am getting this error due to a mismatch of the number of features and neurons at the input layer.

- input layer size should be equal to the number of features.
- output layer size should be equal to the number of classes or class labels.

For example, In my case number of features are 7 and the class labels are 2. I have used layer list `layers = [7, 5, 4, 2]` and two intermediate layers of sizes 5 and 4